# How use current folder name code and put as name file?

Tags: bash

I usualy combine some file PDF to one file PDF and put name with today date.
This code:

```
#get today's date
export LANG=id_ID
export TZ=Asia/Jakarta
TODAY=$(date --date='0 days' '+%Y%m%d')

#combine and name file
pdftk *.pdf cat output document"$TODAY".pdf
```

Now, I want change TODAY with CURRENT FOLDER NAME (ex. folder name: Full01).
I get this code for current folder name:

```
echo "${PWD##*/}"
```

or:

```
printf '%s\n' "${PWD##*/}"
```

How do I use the code? Can anyone help?

Comment: soo `TODAY=$(echo ...)` ?

Comment: I've tried several combinations of existing code, all not working. Haven't found any code that works properly.

Comment: `all not working` What does it mean "not working"? How do you check it? `that works properly` What does it mean to "work properly"? How do you check it?

Comment: @PUSTAKAKORAN.COM : _ I want change TODAY with CURRENT FOLDER NAME_ ... What does it mean to **change** a variable **with** a name? Perhaps it would help if you show with an example the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following code:

```
here=${PWD##*/}
echo $here
```

This is working fine.

What have you tried and what errors do you get?

Comment: It's work! Thank Dominique. Myproblem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
current_folder_name=$(basename "$(readlink -f .)")
```

Comment: Thanks for ceving. I've tried the code, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @PUSTAKAKORAN.COM I have no idea what is not working. You just asked how to get the current folder name. And the above line does it and it works.

Comment: The code provided is correct and can take the name for the current folder. But when put to give a name to the file, the code doesn't say the folder name, but it says "current_folder_name"

Comment: Put a `$` in front. And maybe read a beginners tutorial about shell scripting.

Comment: I use code: pdftk *.pdf cat output document"$current_folder_name".pdf. 
The resulting filename should be documentNAME-FOLDER.pdf, but it will be document$current_folder_name.pdf

Comment: Maybe you use [single quotes instead of double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).